# How to enable OpenSSL for laravel installation in fedora

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, installation

I am trying to install laravel framework using composer in fedora. So I have downloaded the files from github to the server. Then added the composer.phar to the same laravel directory. Then from the same directory I have executed :

```
php composer.phar install
```

Then I am getting the following error :

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                 
 You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https
```

I checked the phpinfo file and I found the following:

```
Native OpenSSL support  enabled 
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.0d-fips 8 Feb 2011
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.0d-fips 8 Feb 2011
```

What is the problem here ? How can I overcome this issue ? I found some explanations for wamp. But my server is fedora. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Your web server is probably using a different php.ini file from the command line. Run the command below to see the installed modules

```
php -m
```

If openssl is missing, use this command to see the location of the php.ini file used by command line and enable the openssl module in there by adding extension=openssl.so

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Comment: How can I enable OpenSSL there ? For fedora ?

Comment: Assuming the CLI is the same installation of PHP as your web server, you should just need to add extension=openssl.so to a new line in the correct php.ini

Comment: actually when I run phpinfo() its coming from /etc/ . And when I hit php -i | grep php.ini, I got path "Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib" and there is ni php.ini file there as well

Comment: If there's no file PHP will just use the defaults. Your best bet is to copy your file. cp /usr/local/lib/php.ini /etc/